# Handling jsonp response after making call

Tags: parsing, jsonp

I'm a newbie to jsonp.
 I'm trying to make a jsonp call since I have to make a cross-domain request.
The following code snippet is used to make the call -

```
 function makeCall(){
    jQuery.getJSON("http://<servername>:<port number>/JSONServices/getJsonInfo?jsonp=?", 
        function(data) {
        alert("data is: "+data[0].name);
    });
}
```

I'm making this call on the onload event of the body tag. The response being returned is a json array. I'm facing the following problems -

1. the response is visible from the net panel of firebug but the alert is not popping anything
2. i have no idea as to how to extract the data from the jsonp call

   Any ideas as to where I'm making mistake and how to resolve it would be highly appreciated.

   Thanks & Regards,

   meamitava.

Answer (score 0):

Your url should look like this:

```
http://<servername>:<port number>/JSONServices/getJsonInfo?callback=?
```

so that means changing the 'jsonp=?' for 'callback=?'